# Using ref with React.createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, createelement, use-ref

I've got a reusable heading component that allows me to pass a `tag` prop, creating any sort of heading (h1, h2, h3 etc). Here's that component:

**heading.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

import s from './Heading.scss';

interface HeadingProps {
  tag: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6';
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
}

export const Heading = ({ tag, children, className }: HeadingProps) => {
  const Tag = ({ ...props }: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>) =>
    React.createElement(tag, props, children);

  return <Tag className={s(s.heading, className)}>{children}</Tag>;
};
```

However, I'm coming across a use case where I'd like to be able to have a `ref`, using the `useRef()` hook, on the `Tag`, so that I can access the element and animate with GSAP. However, I can't figure out how do this using `createElement`.

I've tried to do it by adding a `ref` directly to the `Tag` component, and adding it to the `Tag` props like so:

```
import React, { ReactNode, useRef } from 'react';

import s from './Heading.scss';

interface HeadingProps {
  tag: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6';
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
}

export const Heading = ({ tag, children, className }: HeadingProps) => {
  const headingRef = useRef(null);
  const Tag = ({ ...props }: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>) =>
    React.createElement(tag, props, children, {ref: headingRef});

  return <Tag className={s(s.heading, className)} ref={headingRef}>{children}</Tag>;
};
```

I receive the error `Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>'.`

What am I doing wrong, and how can I safely add a `ref` to the component?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use object spread to add the `ref` to the `props`:

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

const Heading = ({ tag, children, className }) => {
  const headingRef = useRef(null);
  const Tag = (props) => React.createElement(tag, {ref: headingRef, ...props }, children);
  
  useEffect(() => { console.log(headingRef); }, []); // demo - use the ref

  return <Tag>{children}</Tag>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Heading tag="h1">h1</Heading>
    <Heading tag="h2">h2</Heading>
    <Heading tag="h3">h3</Heading>
  </div>,
  root
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; left: 50% !important; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

However, creating a component inside another component would mean that component would be recreated on each render. You can avoid that by using `useMemo()`. However an easier option would be to render the `tag` itself as JSX:

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

const Heading = ({ tag: Tag, children, className }) => {
  const headingRef = useRef(null);
  
  useEffect(() => { console.log(headingRef); }, []); // demo - use the ref

  return <Tag className={className} ref={headingRef}>{children}</Tag>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Heading tag="h1">h1</Heading>
    <Heading tag="h2">h2</Heading>
    <Heading tag="h3">h3</Heading>
  </div>,
  root
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; left: 50% !important; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to forward ref and then pass it not as a child or element, but as it's property.

Here is documentation on ref forwarding: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Here is code exapmles for heading without intermediate component creation:

```js
import React, { ReactNode, useRef } from "react";

import s from "./Heading.scss";

interface HeadingProps {
  tag: "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6";
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
}

export const Heading = forwardRef(
  ({ tag: Tag, children, className }: HeadingProps, headingRef) => {
    return (
      <Tag className={s(s.heading, className)} ref={headingRef}>
        {children}
      </Tag>
    );
  }
);

export const HeadingWithoutJSX = forwardRef(
  ({ tag, children, className }: HeadingProps, headingRef) => {
    return createElement(
      tag,
      { className: s(s.heading, className), ref: headingRef},
      children
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: I've been messing around with that, but do I pass it to the `Heading` component, or `Tag`?

Comment: I added code examples with and without jsx. But I removed intermediate component, since there is not need for it.